# Is it slower to install one package at a time or all at once using conda?

Tags: conda, conda-forge

I have just freshly installed the latest Anaconda and need to install 12 packages from `conda-forge`.  Is or should it be slower to install them all at once or one at a time?  (The environment solving times are so long that I answering this question myself by trial would take days.)

I first installed Miniconda 3.10 and then created two conda environments 3.9 & 3.7 containing anaconda.
I also did:

```
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda config --append channels conda-forge
```

This resulted in "defaults" being listed above "conda-forge" in `.condarc`, so I did not have to prepend defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Declare all requirements at creation

Yes, it is absolutely slower to install packages one at a time mostly because the solver has to solve the environment each time.

For fastest environment setup, declare all requirements at creation time and use `mamba` (a faster frontend for working with Conda environments). Also, using a YAML to define the environment can help with this.

##### Example

```bash
mamba create -n py39 python=3.9 numpy scipy scikit-learn
```

or with YAML

**py39.yaml**

```yaml
name: py39
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - numpy
  - scipy
  - scikit-learn
```

```bash
mamba env create -f py39.yaml
```

---

#### Note on distributions

If one plans to prioritize Conda Forge (may not apply to OP), then be aware that an Anaconda **base** is a poor choice. Anaconda is effectively incompatible with that configuration. Miniconda is more compatible, but prioritizing `conda-forge` effectively converts it to [a Miniforge variant](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge).

For those wanting state-of-the-art performance, I recommend [the Mambaforge **base** distribution](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge). It is preconfigured to  prioritize `conda-forge` channel and includes the `mamba` front-end.

Comment: Sorry, I have clarified that I prioritized default, not conda-forge.

Comment: Yes, the other comments might not be 100% applicable though.

Comment: I edited to move that to a note and deemphasize it.